# Cannot open type library file: 'msxml.dll': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to do a reverse engineering to old .net tool written with c++.
The problem begins in this line:
import "msxml.dll" named_guids

I understand this is old system dll file which currently replaced with msxml3.dll or msxml6.dll.
I found both msxml3.dll and msxml6.dll in system32 folder and mange to do import but then this error appears:
error C2653: 'MSXML' : is not a class or namespace name

Please advice and spread some light on this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solution: change msxml to msxml3 and change MSXML to MSXML2